# Trying to use Crystal's Bycrypt library - "invalid salt size"

Tags: bcrypt, crystal-lang

I'm trying to hash + salt user passwords with the Bcrypt library that ships with Crystal.

The following code produces an "Invalid salt size" error, when run in a playground.

```
require "crypto/bcrypt"

user = "Jones"
pass = "password"

temp = Crypto::Bcrypt.new(pass, user)
```

[Relevant source code](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/c2c2276ec667171af5c2347490f49acdbdc4a3ca/src/crypto/bcrypt.cr#L53)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Crypto::Bcrypt::Password` API,  don't directly use `Crypto::Bcrypt`.

You don't use the username in the BCrypt hash generation, the API will use a random value as the salt.

```
bcryptHash = Crypto::Bcrypt::Password.create("password123")
```

See https://crystal-lang.org/api/master/Crypto/Bcrypt/Password.html

Comment: So basically 'Crypto::Bcrypt::Password.create(user + pass)`?

Comment: You only should hash the secret value, no real point in concatenating the username, using a username as a salt is not a good practice in general, but its absolutely pointless with bcrypt, the whole point of bcrypt is that it safely abstracts salt management away from you.

Comment: `hash = Crypto::Bcrypt::Password.new(pass)` results in an index out of bounds error for me.

Comment: The `new` method is for constructing the object from the serialized bcrypt hash, if you want to create a hash from a password, use the `create` method like the example.